# UPDATE query using value as condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have an update query which takes the form:

```
 update myTable
    set aColumn = case when t2.someValue = 3 then 1 else 0 end
  from myTable
  inner join anotherTable t2 on t2.id = myTable.id
```

Trouble is, it doesn't work.

The 'case' or t2.someValue seems to be being ignored, and every row in myTable gets the same value (0) in aColumn - including those rows where t2.someValue = 3.

Is this a problem with SQL Server, or have I done something wrong?

EDIT: My updated query, based on a comment below...

```
declare @myTable table  (row_id int, aCol int, bCol int)

insert into @myTable
values
(1,0,0),
(2,0,0),
(3,0,0),
(4,0,0),
(5,0,0)

declare @anotherTable table (row_id int, col_id int, someValue int)
insert into @anotherTable
values
(1,1,9),
(1,2,8),
(1,3,7),
(4,3,6),
(5,5,5)

select * from @myTable

update t
set t.aCol = case when t2.col_id = 1 then t2.someValue else t.aCol end,
    t.bCol = case when t2.col_id = 3 then t2.someValue else t.bCol end
from @myTable t
left join @anotherTable t2 on t2.row_id = t.row_id
where t2.col_id IN (1,2,3,5)

select * from @myTable
```

This doesn't update the bCol of the 1st row with a 7 which it should...

```
row_id  aCol    bCol
1   9   0
2   0   0
3   0   0
4   0   6
5   0   0
```

Comment: I think there is no flaw in this statement

Comment: This seems to work. Check the data in your anotherTable. Check the update statement before with a select. Check the case statement result. I did exactly the same out of curiosity and it works fine. You can check it [here](http://rextester.com/XZIAEN55355)

Comment: `SELECT`ing like RigertaDemiri said should be your first reaction: `select aColumn = case when t2.someValue = 3 then 1 else 0 end, * from myTable inner join anotherTable t2 on t2.id = myTable.id`

Comment: I think the syntax is completely wrong. Update query cant contain from clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this -

```
update myTable
set aColumn = (case when t2.someValue = 3 then 1 else 0 end)
from myTable
inner join anotherTable t2 on t2.id = myTable.id
```

Comment: The UPDATE does work - it runs without error (on an in-memory table).

Comment: I tried a SELECT and it looks OK. I think the problem is that an UPDATE works by updating the column for every row - what I really want is to only update the column when the CASE becomes true - and that doesn't happen... so the column gets re-updated lots of times, overwriting the correct value with the incorrect one.

Comment: @radders, thanks for letting me know this syntax. I never know this. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: @radders then maybe you should change your CASE like this?
`set aColumn = case when t2.someValue = 3 then 1 else aColumn end`

Comment: Having 0 in else condition can never be the cause of failing of query.

Comment: @RigertaDemiri, not fully tracking, but can't the `ELSE` part be exchanged for filtering out unwanted records at `WHERE` or `JOIN` clauses?

Comment: @KtX2SkD yes, that as well.

Answer (score 1):

From your edit... you have a 1:Many relationship and this is why it's not happening. You have 3 rows in @anotherTable which can join to tod_id = 1 in @myTable. This is why your update isn't working correctly.

```
declare @myTable table  (row_id int, aCol int, bCol int)

insert into @myTable
values
(1,0,0),
(2,0,0),
(3,0,0),
(4,0,0),
(5,0,0)

declare @anotherTable table (row_id int, col_id int, someValue int)
insert into @anotherTable
values
(1,1,9),
(1,2,8),
(1,3,7),
(4,3,6),
(5,5,5)

select 
    t.* 
    ,t2.*
from @myTable t
left join @anotherTable t2 on t2.row_id = t.row_id
where t2.col_id IN (1,2,3,5)


+--------+------+------+--------+--------+-----------+
| row_id | aCol | bCol | row_id | col_id | someValue |
+--------+------+------+--------+--------+-----------+
|      1 |    0 |    0 |      1 |      1 |         9 | --notice the implied cross join as 
|      1 |    0 |    0 |      1 |      2 |         8 | --row_id 1 is duplicated
|      1 |    0 |    0 |      1 |      3 |         7 | --3 times
|      4 |    0 |    0 |      4 |      3 |         6 |
|      5 |    0 |    0 |      5 |      5 |         5 |
+--------+------+------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

Comment: I've updated @scsimon's example to better reflect my situation....
and it doesn't work.

Comment: see my update @radders, it has to do with your data structure

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I can't do anything about the data structure - it is what it is....

Comment: well then you need to add a different condition to your update... explain this. How would you determine which one of the rows in `@anotherTable` should be used to update that row in `@myTable`? Perhaps you want to use the row with the largest number in the col_id column? Perhaps the first one based off the col_id column? You have to provide some logic to limit the join to 1:1. If you can articulate this, then we can code it @radders

Comment: Given that the update either changes or preserves the current value (by setting it to itself), I would expect myTable to be updated by all the matching rows in anotherTable... If I perform the updates as 2 discrete updates, with one of the col_ids in the where clause, it works. It's just messy as I have a dozen such updates to perform. @scsimon

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Given the advice above - esp. from SCSimon - I have to admit that what I was trying to do was unusual, and too much of an edge-case, for SQL (almost any flavour) to understand.

I have resorted to making the updates to the 12 individual columns as seperate little update statements.

Not as elegant, maybe, but it works without error.
I also doubt that it actually takes any longer to run than a complex query would.